# How to pass the answer for a discord bot from a json file with variables?

Tags: json, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to have a .json file where I store all the data about the commands and the answers. Is it possible, to convert
`{"message": "'<@' + msg.mention.members.first().id + '>'"}` the message with all its variables so that discord can understand it when calling msg.channel.send? What I have so far is:

```
msg.channel.send(commands[i].message);
```

But Discord displays the message instead of interpreting it. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: commands[i] is basically the .json file where the commands are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
msg.channel.send(eval(commands[i].message));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Nicolas!**

Most of the larger bots you may see around server use a command handler.
A command handler (often called CMD handler) is a function or method that dynamically read a directory most often or something else.
This is an easy way to make your code more readable and easier for you the developer to create commands!

So say you have a directory/folder that looks like the following:

```
MyDiscordBot
¦---package.json
¦---index.js
¦---Commands
¦   ----Help.js
¦   ----Kick.js
```

You can easily read the directory with fs [readdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and require the file through a loop of the directory. Then execute an exported function or method in that file.

Not sure if that is what you meant, but if it was - for more info you can use discord.js guide for a command handler!

Hope this helped :)